# Replace a Text in excel with another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to replace the "1" in the columns by the column's header text.
[image]

It says about circular reference... Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: A formula cannot refer to itself.  You will need vba.

Comment: You can use that formula in a different column then `paste values` it into the correct column, or why not just use find and replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for column **A** with the header in row **#1**:

[image]

Run this short macro:

```
Sub UseHeader()
    Dim v As String, rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A:A")

    v = rng(1).Value
    rng.Replace What:="1", replacement:=v
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]

To do this for multiple columns, you need to specify which columns have headers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a simple solution that identifies which mutually exclusive columns have a 1 in them.

Comment: Or you can use INDEX/MATCH so if there are a lot of columns the OP does not need to keep adding nested IFs: `=INDEX($D$1:$F$1,MATCH(1,D2:F2,0))` and also the user can change the headers and the values will change without modifying many hard coded values.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to create new columns, I need to replace the existent "1" with "X", "Y" or "Z"..

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Solution :

Say There are three columns with Heads in Row 1 : A1=X, B1=Y, C1=Z

1. Copy the entire data of three columns and paste it in Column D,E,F and again paste it in Column G, H, I.
2. Now in D,E,F Set Enter Formula :

D2=D1, E2=E1 and F2=F1.
Copy these the formulae down the rows.

3. In Set G, H and I Column Enter Formula :
   G2: =if(A2=1,D2,"")
   Copy Formula of G2 in H2 and I2
4. Copy the formula of G2,H2 and I2 down the rows
5. So you get desired result in Set 3 of Columns G, H and I
6. Copy the region of G,H and I and paste values
7. If you want now Columns A,B..F can be deleted.